# QDialog with label that I'm trying to paint

Tags: qt, class, label

from my main window I am launching a dialog which has a label, in which I am trying to paint.

So, the dialog's header file (.h) has two classes, one for the dialog itself and one for my label. So, my label's class is this:

```
class MyImage : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
        explicit MyImage(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);
};
```

and in the .cpp, along with the constructor of my QDialog I have the constructor of my MyImage class and the paintEvent function:

```
MyImage::MyImage(QWidget *parent)
: QLabel(parent)
{
    /*...*/
}

void MyImage::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QLabel::paintEvent(e);
    QPainter painter(image_label);
    painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor(0,0,0,180)),1,Qt::DashLine));
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255,255,255,120)));
    painter.drawRect(selectionRect);
}
```

The `image_label` is a MyImage object. On the constructor of my QDialog I do the following so as to add it to my QDialog's layout:

```
mainLayout->addWidget(image_label);
```

But it is null. I get an error message on output (`cannot add null widget`) and when I try to add a pixmap to the `image_label` the program crashes.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
void MyImage::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    // QPainter painter(image_label); <- Only paint onto yourself.
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor(0,0,0,180)),1,Qt::DashLine));
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255,255,255,120)));
    painter.drawRect(selectionRect);
}
```

Do not call the base class as any output will be overwritten by the new `QPainter`.  It is crashing because `image_label` is null.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't seem to get it...
I've 2 .h files. One for my dialog, one for my label. In the .h for my label I have declared a public object MyLabel image_label, and then I am not able to access it from my dialog's functions. If i do the opposite (declare it at my Dialog's header) I cannot access it through the function PaintEvent. What's wrong?

Comment: Please post your header files, I can't see why you would want to do what are saying.  For what purpose would you have a `MyImage` instance on the stack, as a `MyImage` member variable?  Your dialog requires one, but it should be created on the heap - like all `QObject` derived instances.  What do you mean you "cannot access it" - does it not compile, does it just crash, or does it do nothing?

Comment: I solved my problem, though I don't know if this is the best solutions around: my header file: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0FYI my cpp file: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0FYJ  thanks a lot!